# Web Api returns 500 until first page visit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm running an Asp.Net MVC web app at

`localhost:8049`

and an Asp.Net Web Api at

`localhost:8049/api`

using a virtual directory in IIS Express. Everything seems to work fine when I visit a page on the web app, which makes calls to the api. But if I try to hit the api directly using a tool like SoapUI without visiting a page first, it throws this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided,
>   or the provided impersonation level is invalid.

But the error isn't always the same. Sometimes it's Microsoft.CSharp or System.Net.Http, but it's always a FileLoadException of some kind.

As long as I navigate to a web page first, everything works. Is there any way to fix this or is it just a quirk of virtual directories in IIS Express?

Comment: Will [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28546468/296861) relate to your question? Sometime, **Clear Solution** and deleting everything inside `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` solves the problem.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work